# How to specify boundary condition in a system of PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

I have this system of PDE below. But upon running the code I get an error:

```
R = 3.95;
gamma1 = 0.2667;
gamma2 = 0.35;
```

This is the system of equations, initial conditions, and boundary conditions:

```
eqns = {Derivative[0, 1][mT][phi, t] == Derivative[2, 0][mT][phi, t],
   Derivative[0, 1][mB][phi, t] == 
    gamma1*mT[phi, t]*cB[r, phi, t] - gamma2*mB[phi, t] + 
     Derivative[2, 0][mB][phi, t],
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][cB][r, phi, t] == 
    Derivative[2, 0, 0][cB][r, phi, t] + 
     1./r^2*Derivative[0, 2, 0][cB][r, phi, t],
 (*initial condition*)
   mT[phi, 0] == 0.001, mB[phi, 0] == 0, cB[r, phi, 0] == 0.005,

 (*boundary condition*)
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][cB][R, phi, 
     t] == -gamma1*mT[phi, t]*cB[R, phi, t] + gamma2*mB[phi, t]
   };
```

I try to solve it:

```
usol = NDSolveValue[
  eqns, {mT, mB, cB}, {r, 0, R}, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 
   0, 1}]
```

However, I get this error:

```
NDSolveValue::derlen: The length of the derivative operator Derivative[0,1] in (mT^(0,1))[phi,t] is not the same as the number of arguments.
```

I think the problem is that in the boundary condition I try to make a derivative at R = 3.95, which I already pass it as an argument. How can I pass the boundary condition in a proper way?

Comment: The number  of arguments should be `3` for all functions in your pde-system!?!

Comment: All functions should depend on `[r,phi,t]`. It is necessary to exclude `theta` from `NDSolve`. What is expected to receive? Boundary conditions must be formulated at least at `r=R`. The initial data is the solution. Need to change for `mb[r,phi,0]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just debugged code in which I changed the initial data for `mB[r,phi,0]`:

```
R = 3.95;
gamma1 = 0.2667;
gamma2 = 0.35; r0 = 10^-5;
eqns = {Derivative[0, 0, 1][mT][r, phi, t] == 
    Derivative[0, 2, 0][mT][r, phi, t], 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][mB][r, phi, t] == 
    gamma1*mT[r, phi, t]*cB[r, phi, t] - gamma2*mB[r, phi, t] + 
     Derivative[0, 2, 0][mB][r, phi, t], 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][cB][r, phi, t] == 
    Derivative[2, 0, 0][cB][r, phi, t] + 
     1./r^2*Derivative[0, 2, 0][cB][r, phi, t]};
(*initial condition*)
ic = {mT[r, phi, 0] == 0.001, mB[r, phi, 0] == 0.001, 
   cB[r, phi, 0] == 0.005};
(*boundary condition*)
bc = {mT[r0, phi, t] == .001, mT[R, phi, t] == .001, 
   mT[r, 0, t] == .001, mT[r, 2*Pi, t] == .001, 
   mB[r0, phi, t] == .001, mB[R, phi, t] == .001, mB[r, 0, t] == .001,
    mB[r, 2*Pi, t] == .001, cB[r0, phi, t] == .005, 
   cB[r, 0, t] == .005, cB[r, 2*Pi, t] == .005, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][cB][R, phi, 
     t] == -gamma1*mT[R, phi, t]*cB[R, phi, t] + 
     gamma2*mB[R, phi, t]*(1 - Exp[-100*t])};
usol = NDSolve[{eqns, bc, ic}, {mT, mB, cB}, {r, r0, R}, {phi, 0, 
   2*Pi}, {t, 0, 1}]

{Table[Plot3D[
   Evaluate[mT[r, phi, t] /. First[usol]], {r, r0, R}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi},
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue,
    AxesLabel -> {"r", "phi", "mT"}], {t, .25, 1, .25}], 
 Table[Plot3D[
   Evaluate[mB[r, phi, t] /. First[usol]], {r, r0, R}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi},
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue,
    AxesLabel -> {"r", "phi", "mB"}], {t, .25, 1, .25}], 
 Table[Plot3D[
   Evaluate[cB[r, phi, t] /. First[usol]], {r, r0, R}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi},
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"r", "phi", "cB"}], {t, .25, 
   1, .25}]}
```

[image: fig1]